# Ubuntu 16.04 ArangoDB3E uninstall error

Tags: 16.04, bug-reporting

This question is specific to the errors faced by installing a corrupted ArangoDB Enterprise version, this prevents further installation of other packages and my aim is to solve it.

I get the following error when I try to install / remove packages:

```
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
(Reading database ... 252333 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing arangodb3e (3.3.3) ...
Failed to stop arangodb3e.service: Unit arangodb3e.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package arangodb3e (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
failed to locate javascript.app-path directory, its neither available in '/var/lib/arangodb3-apps' nor in '//var/lib/arangodb3-apps'
FATAL ERROR: EXIT_FAILED - "exit with error"
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 arangodb3e
```

and I've tried the following, still no luck:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq arangodb3e
```

Comment: After adding the repository for the arangoDB and trying to re-install / remove it, this is what I get: `sudo apt-get install arangodb3e
..
dpkg: error processing package arangodb3e (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 arangodb3e
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: First of all it seems that chosen Enterprise Edition, it makes problem to be non-reproducible. Did you tried to follow [their Ubuntu guide](https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/ubuntu/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to fix:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/arangodb3e.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq arangodb3e
sudo apt-get remove arangodb3e
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and now I can install / reinstall other software including ArangoDB Enterprise, the install turned out to be a rouge install.

To remove all arango data:

```
cd etc
sudo rm -rf arangodb3

cd /var/run
sudo rm -rf arangodb/


cd /usr/share
sudo rm -rf arangodb3

cd /etc/lib
sudo rm -rf aranogdb3/

cd /var/lib
sudo rm -rf arangodb3/

cd /var/lib
sudo rm -rf arangodb3e/
sudo rm -rf arangdodb3-apps/

cd /var/log
sudo rm -rf arangodb3/

cd /usr/share/doc
sudo rm -rf arangodb3/

cd /var/tmp
sudo rm -rf arangod
```